# JQuery - Unable to add a transition on another object after parent is toggled

Tags: jquery, css

I've been lurking this site for a few years, but have just recently decided to really try to expand my front-end horizons, and thought now would probably be a good time to sign up.

I'm relatively comfortable with HTML & CSS, but am just now starting to take a deep dive into JS.  I wrote this simple little slide out widget, and while the first half is working fine (the process of opening and closing the drawer), the second portion, where you click the ball and it enlarges does not want to work.  I'm sure there is likely a really simple solution, or explanation why my approach is wrong, but I cannot seem to figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Here is the JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
 var box = $('#box');
 var drawer = $('#drawer');
 var ball = $('.ball');

 box.click(function(){
 drawer.toggleClass("open");
 });
 ball.click(function(){
 ball.toggleClass("ball-lg");
 });
});
```

[Link to the codepen.](http://codepen.io/brandonjcreek/pen/RKmxjB)

Comment: remove the negative `z-index` from `#drawer`

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was going to be something I simple that I overlooked.  I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. Want me to submit this as an answer?

Comment: Totally! It certainly solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the negative `z-index` from `#drawer`. A negative z-index will put the element under/behind all default elements with a static position and/or a higher z-index, so unless the z-index for, say, `body` has explicitly been defined to be less than -1, the element will be unclickable.

Here's an example

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">click me</a>
```